# Client-Side validation with Telerik ASP.NET Ajax doesn't work

Tags: c#, telerik, client-side, validation

I'm currently working with telerik Radcontrols ASP.NET Ajax, and i want to create client side validation for my page. I created a usercontrol and followed [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/common/validation/defaultcs.aspx) tutorial that i found on the telerik site. Unfortunatly it doesn't work and i have no idea what i've done wrong. Could somebody take a look at my code for me and point me in the right direction?

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ManageAccountControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Docl.WebDoc.Controls.Account.ManageAccountControl" %>

<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
</style>
<div id="CreateUser" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px">

    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadSkinManager ID="QsfSkinManager" runat="server" ShowChooser="true" />
    <telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="QsfFromDecorator" runat="server" DecoratedControls="All" EnableRoundedCorners="false" />
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="rapPanel" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1">
        <div onclick="Validate()">
            <table class="adminProps">
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="ctrlEmail" runat="server">
                        </telerik:RadTextBox></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmail" runat="server" Width="25px">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="regexEmail"
                                ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"
                                runat="server" ControlToValidate="ctrlEmail" ErrorMessage="A valid Email is required!" EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group1" ControlToValidate="ctrlEmail" ErrorMessage="Email is required" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Voornaam</td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="ctrlFirstName" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlFirstName" runat="server" Width="25px">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group1" ControlToValidate="ctrlFirstName" ErrorMessage="FirstName is required" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Achternaam</td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="ctrlLastName" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnLastName" runat="server" Width="25px">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="group1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ctrlLastName" ErrorMessage="LastName is required" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="ctrlCreate" runat="server" Text="Voeg toe"></telerik:RadButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRed" Style="color: red" runat="server" Width="159px"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblGreen" Style="color: green" runat="server" Width="159px"></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server">
                            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" runat="server" Width="174px" BorderColor="Red"
                                BorderWidth="1px" HeaderText="List of errors" EnableClientScript="true" DisplayMode="BulletList" ValidationGroup="group1"></asp:ValidationSummary>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</div>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="LoadingPanel1" runat="server" MinDisplayTime="300">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate() {


        Page_ClientValidate('group1');
    }
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class ManageAccountControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    RootRepos _repos;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _repos = new RootRepos();
        InitCtrls();
        foreach (BaseValidator validator in Page.Validators)
        {
            validator.EnableClientScript = true;
        }

    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ctrlCreate.Click += new System.EventHandler(ctrlCreate_Click);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(Page_Load);
    }


    private void InitCtrls()
    {
        lblRed.Text = string.Empty;
        lblGreen.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    protected void ctrlCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            lblRed.Text = "Name Registered: ";
            lblGreen.Text = ctrlLastName.Text + " " + ctrlFirstName.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            lblRed.Text = "Account not registered! Validation error.";
        }
    }

    private bool CheckIfUserExists()
    {

        if (_repos.AccountRepos.GetSingle(ctrlEmail.Text) != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    private Data.Account CreateAccount(Guid partyid)
    {
        Data.Account account = new Data.Account();
        account.PartyId = partyid;
        account.Name = ctrlEmail.Text;

        return account;
    }

    private Data.Party CreateParty()
    {
        Data.Party party = new Data.Party();
        party.PartyId = Guid.NewGuid();
        party.LastName = ctrlLastName.Text;
        party.Name = ctrlFirstName.Text + " " + ctrlLastName.Text;
        party.FirstName = ctrlFirstName.Text;

        return party;
    }


}
```

Thank you!